# ImportError: cannot import name 'GazeboRosPaths' from 'scripts'

Tags: gazebo, ros2, roslaunch, ros-foxy, ubuntu-20.04

I am trying to run `ros2 launch gazebo_ros gazebo.launch.py` on ROS 2 Foxy. Unfortunately, I came across the following error:

```
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/mubashir/.ros/log/2023-08-30-13-25-29-406060-mubashir-7514
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-2' coro=<LaunchService._process_one_event() done, defined at /opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/launch_service.py:226> exception=ImportError("cannot import name 'GazeboRosPaths' from 'scripts' (/home/mubashir/ros2_foxy_ws/install/pedsim_gazebo_plugin/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scripts/__init__.py)")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/launch_service.py", line 228, in _process_one_event
    await self.__process_event(next_event)
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/launch_service.py", line 248, in __process_event
    visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures(entity, self.__context))
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/utilities/visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures_impl.py", line 45, in visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures
    futures_to_return += visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures(sub_entity, context)
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/utilities/visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures_impl.py", line 45, in visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures
    futures_to_return += visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures(sub_entity, context)
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/utilities/visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures_impl.py", line 45, in visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures
    futures_to_return += visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures(sub_entity, context)
  [Previous line repeated 1 more time]
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/utilities/visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures_impl.py", line 38, in visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures
    sub_entities = entity.visit(context)
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/action.py", line 108, in visit
    return self.execute(context)
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/actions/include_launch_description.py", line 130, in execute
    launch_description = self.__launch_description_source.get_launch_description(context)
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/launch_description_source.py", line 84, in get_launch_description
    self._get_launch_description(self.__expanded_location)
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/launch_description_sources/python_launch_description_source.py", line 51, in _get_launch_description
    return get_launch_description_from_python_launch_file(location)
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/launch_description_sources/python_launch_file_utilities.py", line 62, in get_launch_description_from_python_launch_file
    launch_file_module = load_python_launch_file_as_module(python_launch_file_path)
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/launch_description_sources/python_launch_file_utilities.py", line 37, in load_python_launch_file_as_module
    loader.exec_module(mod)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/share/gazebo_ros/launch/gzserver.launch.py", line 28, in <module>
    from scripts import GazeboRosPaths
ImportError: cannot import name 'GazeboRosPaths' from 'scripts' (/home/mubashir/ros2_foxy_ws/install/pedsim_gazebo_plugin/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scripts/__init__.py)
```

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! The following links may help: [1](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/issues/1050), [2](https://github.com/ros-controls/gazebo_ros2_control/issues/67), and [3](https://answers.ros.org/question/374976/ros2-launch-gazebolaunchpy-from-my-own-launch-file/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the following problem by reinstalling foxy Gazebo package `sudo apt install ros-foxy-gazebo-*`